# State in props is undefined but its correct in return render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, react-state

i'm tying to make a card game on react to learn more of it's working. so here i sthe propblem. There is a array state **Opponents** [name, name1] in **opponents.jsx** which is going throught props to child component **OpponentCards.jsx** and return can read the value ro render the correct name of opponent but when i'm trying to deal with it's value in code before 'return' it has undefined value.

I've found out that it causing by asyncronus of props but idk how to deal with it in correct way. Also if i refresh vite in vscode and do not refresh page of project it starts working correctly.

Opponents.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import OpponentCards from './OpponentCards'

const Opponents = (props) => {

    const [opponents, setOpponents] = useState([])
    const [numberOfPlayers, setNumberOfPlayers] = useState('two')
    
    let updateUsers = (data) => {

        let usersToChange = data.users
        if(usersToChange.find(item => item === localStorage.getItem('name'))){
            while(String(usersToChange[0]) !== localStorage.getItem('name')){
                usersToChange.push(usersToChange[0])
                usersToChange.splice(0,1)
            }        

        }
        
        setOpponents(usersToChange)
        switch (props.users.length) {
            case 2 :
                setNumberOfPlayers('two') 
                return
            case 3 :
                setNumberOfPlayers('three') 
                return
            case 4 :
                setNumberOfPlayers('four') 
                return
        }
    } 

    props.socket.on('getUsersResponse', (data) => {
        updateUsers(data)
    })


    useEffect(() => updateUsers(props) ,[props.users])


    console.log(opponents) //correct array of opponents

    return (
        <div className={numberOfPlayers+'-players'}>
            <div className="opponent one">
                <OpponentCards opponent = {opponents[1]} number={1}  socket= {props.socket}/>
            </div>

            <div className="opponent two">
                <OpponentCards opponent = {opponents[2]} number={3}  socket= {props.socket}/>
            </div>

            <div className="opponent three">
                <OpponentCards opponent = {opponents[2]} number={3}  socket= {props.socket}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Opponents
```

and OpponentCards.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import userLogo from '../../sourses/Untitled.svg'

const OpponentCards = (props) => {

    let [cards, setCards] = useState(0) 
    
    
    let addCard = (name) => {

        if(name === props.opponent){
            setCards(cards => cards +1)
        }
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        props.socket.on('getCardFromDeckToOpponentResponse',(name) => addCard(name))
    },[props.socket])

    console.log(props.opponent)//undefined

    return (
        <>
        <div className="container">
            <h3 className='name'>
                {props.opponent ? props.opponent : 'Player ' + (props.number + 1)}
            </h3>
            <img src={userLogo} />
            <div className="opponentCards">
                {[...Array(cards)].map((elem, index)=> <div key={index} className='card'>x</div>)}
            </div>
        </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default OpponentCards
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `opponents` state is empty when the component renders initially and it will taking some time to get updated when `updateUsers()` executed. So, reading `opponents[1]` will be undefined during that phase.

The return statement of `Opponents.jsx` should be something like

```
return (
  <div className={numberOfPlayers + "-players"}>
    {opponents.map((opponent, index) => (
      <div className={`opponent ${index}`}>
        <OpponentCards
          opponent={opponent}
          number={index}
          socket={props.socket}
        />
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Now it's working, but i still cant get the way why does it work.

Comment: @Dimon1200 `opponents` is initially an empty array, and `Array.prototype.map` handles mapping empty arrays without issue. The result of `[].map(......)` is `[]`, which React also handles without issue as it is perfectly valid JSX. ***Don't forget the React key on the mapped outer `div` element.***